# JQuery custom select - val() does not work

Tags: jquery, select

I have a problem with dropdown list with customSelect.
When I call

```
$('#select_id').val('optionValue');
```

the selected option is not visible.
There is an example http://jsfiddle.net/7ttWj/520/

I have also tried ".trigger('update');", but does not work, as well.

Can you help with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are assigning the value but not adding the `:selected` to said option

Comment: Please include ***all*** necessary code to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Jquery CustomSelect does not change select.

**Source data:**

CustomSelect home page:
http://rixth.github.io/customSelect/

**Decision:**

I spent much time to solve this problem, but I found that standard functional does not allow to change select with "customSelect effect".

The only work decision is to write own code (trick) for this aim.

Here is my code which is works correctly in all common browsers (Firefox, Opera, Chrome, IE 11, Ipad Safari):

**1 step: inside hide div create select without customSelect effect:**

```
<!-- bug fixation with custom select -->
<div style="display:none">

<div id="ad-for-replacement">
<select name="ad" class="combobox ad">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</div>

</div>
<!-- /bug fixation with custom select -->
```

**2 step: create html code for users:**

```
<td class="for-ch">
<select name="ch" class="combobox ch">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
```

**3 step: initialize customSelect:**

```
$("td .combobox").customSelect();
```

**4 step: write realization on jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document.body).delegate('.for-ad .ad', "change", function(){
       var option = $(this).val(); // console.log('option: ' + option);
       var content = $('#ad-for-replacement').html(); // console.log(content);
       $('.for-ad').html(content);
       $('.for-ad option:contains("' + option + '")').prop('selected', true);
       $(".for-ad .combobox").customSelect();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the order.  Set the value before calling customSelect()

http://jsfiddle.net/7ttWj/521/

```
$('.styled').val('three');
var $cs = $('.styled').customSelect();
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are **wrong**. Calling again `.customSelect()` will rerender the controls but they will be freezed.

The correct method is to force a rerender with `.trigger()`:

```
$("#myCustomSelect").val("myvalue");
$("#myCustomSelect").trigger("render");
```

Answer (score 2):

The component has a [render trigger](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect/blob/master/jquery.customSelect.js#L67) that you should use after changing the value:

```
$('#select_id')
  .val('three')
  .trigger('render.customSelect');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ttWj/719/)

Answer (score 0):

In your example jsFiddle, your assignment of the jQuery selector to $cs is wrong, if you just change it to

```
var $cs = $('.styled');
$cs.val('three');
```

then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's the your working code from your fiddle -

```
var $cs = $('.styled');
$cs.val('three');
$cs.customSelect();
```

Comment: Thank you, so I have to call "customSelect()" everytime I programatically change the option?

Comment: When I call multiple times "customSelect()", the select box freeze... you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/7ttWj/523/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this order to work with custom select.

To set a value.

1.First destroy the custom select if already initialized.

```
  $('#select_id').customSelect('destroy');
```

2.Set the value

```
 $('#select_id').val('1');
```

3.Reinitialise the custom select

```
 $('#select_id').customSelect();
```

Comment: This solution made my select box unclickable. I recommend using Jack's solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/27617686/1730061

Comment: It changed my selected value, but for some reason it made my select unclickable after it was re-rendered. It may have been specific to my scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one very easy

$("#select_id").customselect('select',1);